# Dash - how to get callback to autorefresh with no button click?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a few input forms on a dash callback which translate the inputs into a textual summary.

Right now, I have to click a button to refresh that textual summary, but I would like the refresh to be automatic - whenever the user edits the value in out of the input boxes instead.

I've tried changing the `State` variables into `Input` and getting rid of the reference to the button in callback input, but that hasn't helped - I still need to hit the button for the text to refresh.

Is there a way to make the textual summary refresh automatically, whenever user alters an input box?

```
@app.callback(
    Output('desc', 'children'),
    Input('submit-button-choose-event', 'n_clicks'),
    State("full-input-boxes", "children"),
             )
def refresh_desc(n_clicks,children):
    txt = ''
    if children:
        inputs = [i["props"] for i in children["props"]["children"] if i["type"] == "Input"]
        #process the inputs into txt
    return txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing State to Input is the way to go, you need the input `value` of the component :

```python
    @app.callback(
        Output('desc', 'children'),
        Input('full-input-boxes', 'value'))
    def refresh_desc(txt):
        # ...
        return txt
```

This works for the following input types : `text`, `number`, `password`, `email`, `search`.

Comment: thank you @ericlavault . strangely, this does not work - it refreshes when I first load the page but doesn't change when I alter the inputs. I'm using 'children' box because my inputs are dynamic depending on another callback, so I cannot hardcode each entry box unfortunately

Comment: Ok, put that code (which defines the components, and the involved callbacks) into your question so that we can investigate further.